# CartItems routing error using React-Router-Dom v6

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-redux, react-router-component, connected-react-router

I am trying to introduce 'cartItems' functionality to my react-redux app and store the added data in the browser's local storage.

Indeed the problem raises when I try to show cart items by clicking on the cart link at the navbar section.   The error message is **'GET http://localhost:3000/products/undefined 500 (Internal Server Error)'** and **'Uncaught (in promise)'.** and I don't know how to fix the issue.

**Note: the same component 'CartScreen.js'  would display the cart items in both cases, when adding new items to the cart & when also clicking on the cart link at the navbar.**

Please follow the code snippets

Thanks & Regards

App.js

```
import Header from './components/Header';
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import ProductScreen from './screens/ProductScreen';
import CartScreen from './screens/CartScreen';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <main className="py-3">
        <Container>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<HomeScreen />} exact />
            <Route path="/product/">
              <Route path=":id" element={<ProductScreen />} />
              <Route index element={<ProductScreen />} />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/cart" >
              <Route index element={<CartScreen />} />
              <Route path=":productid" element={<CartScreen />} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </Container>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

ProductScreen.js

```
import { useParams, Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import {Row,Col,Image,ListGroup,Button,Card,Form} from 'react-bootstrap';
import Rating from '../components/Rating';
import { listProductDetails } from '../actions/productActions';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import Loader from '../components/Loader';
import Message from '../components/Message';

function ProductScreen() {
  
  const { id } = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [qty, setQty] = useState(1);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const productListDetail = useSelector((state) => state.productDetail);
  const { loading, error, product } = productListDetail;

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProductDetails(id));
  }, [dispatch, id]);
  
  const addToCartHandler = () => {
    navigate(`/cart/${id}?qty=${qty}`);
  };

  return (
    <div> <Link to={-1} className="btn btn-primary my-3">Go Back</Link>
      {loading ? (<Loader />): error ? (<Message variant="danger">{error}</Message>) : (
        <Row>
           <Col md={6}>
             <Image src={product.image} alt={product.name} fluid />
           </Col>
           <Col md={3}>
            <ListGroup variant="flush">
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <h3> {product.name}</h3>
              </ListGroup.Item>
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Rating value={product.rating} text={`${product.numReviews} reviews`}
                  color={'#fae500'}/>
              </ListGroup.Item>
              <ListGroup.Item>Price: ${product.price}</ListGroup.Item>
              <ListGroup.Item>
                Description: {product.description}
              </ListGroup.Item>
            </ListGroup>
          </Col>
          <Col md={3}>
            <Card>
              <ListGroup variant="flush">
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Row>
                    <Col> Price: </Col>
                    <Col>
                      <strong>${product.price} </strong>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </ListGroup.Item>

                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Row>
                    <Col> Status: </Col>
                    <Col>
                      <strong>
                         {product.countInStock > 0 ? 'In Stock' : 'Out of Stock'}
                      </strong>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </ListGroup.Item>
                 {product.countInStock > 0 && (
                 <ListGroup.Item>
                    <Row>
                      <Col> Qty </Col>
                      <Col xs="auto" className="my-1">
                        <Form.Control as="select" value={qty} 
                         onChange={(e) => setQty(e.target.value)}>
                          {[...Array(product.countInStock).keys()].map((x) => (
                              <option key={x + 1} value={x + 1}>{x + 1}</option>))}
                        </Form.Control>
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                  </ListGroup.Item>)}
                  <ListGroup.Item>
                    <Button onClick={addToCartHandler}
                    className="btn btn-primary container-fluid"
                    disabled={product.countInStock === 0}
                    type="button">
                    Add to Cart
                  </Button>
                </ListGroup.Item>
              </ListGroup>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProductScreen;
```

CartScreen.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Col, ListGroup,Row,} from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useLocation, useNavigate, useParams, Link, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import { addToCart } from '../actions/cartAction';
import Message from '../components/Message';

const CartScreen = () => {

  
  const { search } = useLocation();
  const { productid } = useParams();
  const qty = search ? Number(search.split('=')[1]) : 1;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  const { cartItems } = cart;

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(addToCart(productid, qty));
  },[dispatch, productid, qty]);

  return ( 
    <Row>
      <Col md={8}> {cartItems.length === 0 ? (<Message variant="info">
            Go Back To Home Page <Link to="/"></Link> </Message> ) : (
             <ListGroup> {cartItems.map((x) => (
               <ListGroup.Item key={x.product}>
                  {x.name} , {x.qty}
               </ListGroup.Item> ))}
            </ListGroup>)}
      </Col>
      <Col md={4}></Col>
    </Row>
  );
};

export default CartScreen;
```

cartReducers.js

```
import { CART_ADD_ITEM } from '../constants/cartConstants';

export const cartReducer = (state = { cartItems: [] }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CART_ADD_ITEM:

      const item = action.payload;

      const existItem = state.cartItems.find((x) => x.product === item.product);

      if (existItem) {
        return {
          ...state, cartItems: state.cartItems.map((x) =>
            x.product === existItem.product ? item : x),};} 
      else {
        return {
          ...state, cartItems: [...state.cartItems, item],};}
     default:
       return state;
             }
           };
```

cartAction.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { CART_ADD_ITEM } from '../constants/cartConstants';

export const addToCart = (productid, qty) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  
  const { data } = await axios.get(`/products/${productid}`);

  dispatch({
    type: CART_ADD_ITEM,
    payload: {
      product: data._id,
      name: data.name,
      image: data.image,
      price: data.price,
      countInStock: data.countInStock,
      qty,
    },
  });

  localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems));
};
```

store.js

```
import { legacy_createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { composeWithDevTools } from '@redux-devtools/extension';
import {
  productDetailsReducer,
  productListReducer,
} from './reducers/productReducers';
import { cartReducer } from './reducers/cartReducers';

const reducer = combineReducers({
  productList: productListReducer,
  productDetail: productDetailsReducer,
  cart: cartReducer,
});


const cartItemsFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('cartItems')
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems'))
  : [];

const initialState = { cart: { cartItems: cartItemsFromStorage } };
const middleware = [thunk];

const store = legacy_createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export default store;
```

[image]

Comment: You could probably benefit greatly from using a more "organic" redux state persistence solution like [redux-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist) to handle persisting and hydrating/initializing the store for you. You may also want to do the trivial upgrade to using [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) which greatly simplifies configuring the store ***and*** has redux-thunk built-in by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issue here might be resolved by using the same logic in my answer [here](/a/72875538/8690857) to your other [question](/questions/72874131/no-routes-matched-location-for-cartitems-app) regarding route matching. It wasn't explicitly called out as an issue or something the *needed* to be addressed/fixed (*in other words, I thought you'd used the code and had an issue elsewhere*), so adding an answer here for the specific axios issue and resolution.

It looks like navigating to `"/cart"` will result in ***both*** `productid` *and* `qty` being undefined/invalid values, and the `useEffect` hook is unconditionally dispatching the action to add the item & quantity. `productid` is undefined at `` axios.get(`/products/${productid}`) `` in the action creator.

You should only dispatch the `addToCart` action if there is a valid product id and a quantity to add.

```
const CartScreen = () => {
  const { search } = useLocation();
  const { productid } = useParams();
  const qty = search ? Number(search.split('=')[1]) : 1;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  const { cartItems } = cart;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (productid && qty > 0) {
      dispatch(addToCart(productid, qty)); // <-- only dispatch if valid
    }
  }, [dispatch, productid, qty]);

  return ( 
    <Row>
      <Col md={8}>
        {!cartItems.length
          ? (
            <Message variant="info">
              <Link to="/">
                Go Back To Home Page
              </Link>
            </Message>
          ) : (
            <ListGroup>
              {cartItems.map((x) => (
                <ListGroup.Item key={x.product}>
                  {x.name} , {x.qty}
                </ListGroup.Item>
              ))}
            </ListGroup>
          )
        }
      </Col>
      <Col md={4}></Col>
    </Row>
  );
};
```